# Getting placeholder image instead of swatch image. Magento2.3

Tags: magento2.3, swatches

I have some issues with swatch images. Clicking swatches in catalog list pages loads placeholder images instead of real product images.

I noticed that request to get swatch images returns only `small` image and placeholder image for the rest of dimensions.

- I can confirm that swatch images have been set correctly in magento administration.
- I have tried clearing image cache
- I have tried running `php bin/magento catalog:image:resize` to regenerate resized images. Didn't work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I am seeing this too, did you find a solution?

Comment: Same problem here! Did you guys find a solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/etc/view.xml`
If it was not there, add it `view.xml` (should copy it from parent theme).

```
<image id="product_page_image_large_no_frame" type="small_image">
    <width>650</width>
    <height>650</height>
    <frame>false</frame>
</image>

<image id="product_page_image_medium_no_frame" type="small_image">
    <width>650</width>
    <height>650</height>
    <frame>0</frame>
</image>
```

Those are 2 value which triggered while you choose swatch from product grid.
You could change `type="small_image"` to `type="thumbnail"` or `type="image"`

Hope this helps.